# How to check for a List of objects whose values are null?

Tags: c#

I have a List of objects in variable `SanityResults` with only one object whose values are null,I am trying to validate this condition as `if (SanityResults != null)` but fails?how to check for this case?

[image]

```
if (SanityResults != null)
{
     //code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The condition that you are using will check whether `SanityResults` is null or not. But you wanted to check for the properties of all objects inside the list. So the better option is the use of `Any()` if you wanted to check check for any object inside the list is null means you have to use like the following:

```
if(SanityResults.Any(x => x == null))
{
   // This will execute if any one of the object in the list is null
}
```

Now try this, if you wanted to check for properties of each object inside the list:

```
if(SanityResults.Any(x => x.failCount==null || x.htmllist ==null))
{
    // include conditions like this for all required properties
    // this statement will execute if any of the property of any of the objects in the list is null
}
```

Comment: The joys of ienumerable

Comment: Checking if any items in the list are null makes no sense, as it is the *properties* of the items, that should not be null.

Comment: @J.N.: If the item itself is null then there will not be any properties

Comment: @un-lucky : But that is not what OP is dealing with.

Comment: Both presented options make sense to me...first check if the object is null, then check if it's properties are null.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a separate method for is contain null

```
public bool IsContainNull(List<SanityResults> myList)
{
    foreach(var myObject in myList)
    { 
     if(myObject==null) 
      {return false;} 
     else{ 
      foreach(PropertyInfo pi in myObject.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if(pi.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                {
                    string stringValue = (string)pi.GetValue(myObject);
                    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue ))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
               else if(pi.PropertyType == typeof(int))
                {
                    int intValue = (int)pi.GetValue(myObject);
                    if(intValue==null)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

    }
            return false;
```

}
}

Comment: The only edit I would suggest is to check first if `myList` is null, and then inside the first `foreach`, check if `myObject` is null (currently your answer will throw an exception if either of the above are true, when it should just return `true` IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just to throw another similar answer into the ring...

```
if (SanityResults == null || SanityResults.Any(sr => sr == null) || 
    SanityResults.Any(sr => sr.failcount == null && sr.htmllist == null &&
    sr.passcount == null && sr.testsuitename == null))
{
   // Do something if the List is null, if any items in the list are null, 
   // or all of the properties of any item in the list are null
}
```

Comment: You have used `||` to combine conditions, which means all conditions will be executed, so if  `SanityResults == null` then `SanityResults.Any` will throw `NullReference`. another thing to be noted is, if any `sr` is null then its property will throws `NullReference`. right?

Comment: Nope. `||` operators return `true` as soon as any condition evaluates to `true` (`true || false == true`), just as `&&` operators return `false` as soon as any condition evaluates to `false` (`false && true == false`). So there will be no `NullReference` exceptions because I'm testing the "parent" object before the "child" object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the SanityResults is actually not null, and consists of one element with properties, that are null.

What elements are allowed to be null, and what aren't?

If none of the properties are allowed to be null, then go with this:

```
if(SanityResults.Any(x => x.failCount == null || x.passcount == null || x.testsuitename == null || x.htmllist == null))
{
    // Code goes here
}
```

An element in the list, having nothing but null values in it, but having a semantic value in the code, smells a bit though.